# Why does lodash throttle not work within the useWindowSize custom hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm trying to use resize event with throttle. However, it doesn't work. I tried to debug it as follow:

```
import {throttle} from 'lodash'

export function useWindowSize() {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  })

  const handleResize = () => {
    // handle resize code....
  }

  const onWindowResize = () => {
    console.log('Throttle') // <-- this does print out
    throttle(() => {
      console.log('bam') // <-- this doesn't print out
    }, 100)
  }

  useEventListener('resize', onWindowResize)

  return windowSize
}
```

As seen from the code above, I've been trying to log out before I use the `throttle` func from `lodash`. It does print out, but the log inside the `throttle` itself doesn't. Anyone knows why this maybe and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline function recrated on every render. Just make sure the throttle function will be the same function on next render. You can use useCallback hook.

```
export function useWindowSize() {
   const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
     width: undefined,
     height: undefined
  });
  const someFunction = (e) => {
     console.log("bam", e); // 
  };
  const throttleFn = useCallback(throttle(someFunction, 1000), []);

  const onWindowResize = (e) => {
     console.log("Throttle", e); 
     throttleFn(e);
  };

  useEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);

  return windowSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve this and something similar as the following code works for me:

```
export function useWindowSize() {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  })

  const handleResize = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('handleResize') // It does log this out
    // handle the resize...
  }, [windowSize])


  useEventListener('resize', throttle(handleResize, 4000)) // call it here instead
  return windowSize
}
```